# Do I need to capture self weakly inside a UIAlertController's action completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, closures, weak-references, retain-cycle

I've read that self doesn't need to be captured weakly in a `UIAlertController` action completion handler if the `UIAlertController` reference is `weak`. The reason being that `UIAlertController` is designed to release everything once it's done executing, provided that you hold a weak reference to it.

[Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883003/6036023).

Here is a hypothetical example:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)

// The action's completion handler captures the alert controller weakly, but self is not captured weakly
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "action title", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] _ in
    guard let alertController = alert else {
        return
    }
    // The alert controller's action triggers a server call method owned by self
    self.serverCall { result in

            // We use the alertController inside the closure
            print(alertController.actions)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Do stuff on the main thread with the result
            }
    }
})

alert.addAction(action)
```

Is this a valid way to keep a weak reference to the `UIAlertController`?

Will keeping a strong reference to self, in this case, cause a retain cycle or not?

Comment: I guess yes , because you use a DispatchQueue in your closure and it causes your closure's not Immidiate , you it make a memory leak for your project

Comment: I think that your approach makes sense, but why would you need a reference to UIAlertController in the action handler?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a valid way to keep a weak reference to the UIAlertController?:

Yes, it's true

Will keeping a strong reference to self, in this case, cause a retain cycle or not?
weak self will reference with value, when base class is destroy, it realy free memory. So it not retain cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In the example code, `UIAlertController` is not a `var` of the view controller. In this case, you don't need weakify the `self` in the action's handler (btw, the parameter of the handler should be `UIAlertAction -> Void`).

When the view controller which calls `present` retains the `UIAlertController`, it needs `[weak self]` in the handler. In other cases it doesn't need `weak`.

Besides, the link you provides clarifies it.